# FastAPI DB Session error: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to init a new session in FastAPI but I'm having the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'query'
```

My code is:

**database.py**

```
class Database:
"""Handles database connection."""

DATABASE_URL = (
    "postgresql://{db_username}:{db_passwd}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
)

@staticmethod
def engine() -> Engine:
    """Creates a database engine."""
    return create_engine(
        Database.DATABASE_URL.format(
            db_username=settings.DB_USERNAME,
            db_passwd=settings.DB_PASSWORD,
            db_host=settings.DB_HOST,
            db_port=settings.DB_PORT,
            db_name=settings.DB_NAME,
        )
    )


@staticmethod
def __get_session() -> Session:
    """Creates a local session and returns it."""
    session_class = sessionmaker(
        autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=Database.engine()
    )
    return session_class()

@staticmethod
def create_new_session() -> Generator[Session, None, None]:
    """Initializes a new db session and returns it."""
    db = Database.__get_session()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

**snippet from repository class:**

```
db_session = return Database.create_new_session()

vendor_response_model = (
    db_session.query(VendorResponseModel)
    .filter(VendorResponseModel.hash_key == hash_key)
    .order_by(desc(VendorResponseModel.dt_created))
    .limit(1)
    .first()
)
return self.from_orm(vendor_response_model)
```

The error happens when `db_session.query()` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Database.create_new_session()` returns a *Generator* of *Session*.
For using the Session object included in it, you need to wrap it in a *context manager* and use `with` statement for accessing the internal object on enter and make it run the final code to close the session on *exit*.

In the case of this code (that represents most of how FastAPI users do), you should wrap the create_new_session in a *context manager class* or use the decorator `@contextmanager`.

a. If you want to use a *context manager class* wrapper, refer to this FastAPI doc: [using-context-managers-in-dependencies-with-yield](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/#using-context-managers-in-dependencies-with-yield)

b. A more straightforward approach that I used is the decorator + with statement. The code looks like:

**database.py**

```
...
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Database:
...

    @staticmethod
    @contextmanager
    def create_new_session() -> Generator[Session, None, None]:
        """Initializes a new db session and returns it."""
        db = Database.__get_session()
        try:
            yield db
        finally:
            db.close()
```

**snippet from repository class:**

```
db_session = return Database.create_new_session()

with db_session as db_session: # with this will access the inner Session and guarantee it's closed on the final of its usage
    vendor_response_model = (
        db_session.query(VendorResponseModel)
        .filter(VendorResponseModel.hash_key == hash_key)
        .order_by(desc(VendorResponseModel.dt_created))
        .limit(1)
        .first()
    )
return self.from_orm(vendor_response_model)
```

It's important to close the open sessions, or else you can have many idle connections and have issues in your database ([ref](https://towardsdatascience.com/fastapi-cloud-database-loading-with-python-1f531f1d438a)).

I hope this can help!